# Remove blue dot indicator (my location) from Google Maps in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

How do I disable my location indicator on Google Maps. I am making an app which uses location tracking. Person A can see Person B's location on map. For indicating Person B's location on map I am using custom marker but the problem is when looking from Person A's perspective (my perspective) I can see my own location alongside Person B's. Basically I don't need to see my location in any use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `myLocationEnabled` property to false in the `GoogleMap` widget